# System.Windows.Forms.Timer object does not tick when loaded from an activated assembly (plugin)

Tags: c#, winforms, reflection, plugins

I am currently working on a project that loads assemblies (plugins) into the primary AppDomain space (via Reflection's Assembly.LoadFile() and the Activator class).  As a part of the API with the plugins, the hosting application can request a Control-derived object to display on the host's form.

Essentially: the "hosting application" is a WinForms application that can load assemblies that contain controls.  The hosting application loads the assemblies (via Assembly.LoadFile()) and then asks for a control from each assembly.  The control is then rendered (added to a container) on the form.

Everything appears to work fine (buttons, labels, images, etc.) with the control and it IS interactive.  However, if a Timer (WinForms component - NOT System.Threading.Timer) is used in the form - it does NOT tick.  If the control is used directly in the host (when referenced as a dependency), the timer will tick as expected.

Is anyone aware of problems with WinForms Timer not being able to properly hook into the message pump if loaded from an assembly?

Answer (score 1):

It isn't clear what "AppDomain space" might mean.  Guessing: here's an excellent [blog post](http://do-the-right-things.blogspot.com/2009/07/cross-appdomain-winform-implementation.html) that describes the hazards of loading controls in a secondary AppDomain.  The key part is this one, followed by advice on how to make it work:

> Windows Forms only supports isolating
>   top-level windows via app domains. It
>   does not support parent-child
>   relationships across domains. Many
>   people have assumed that because
>   Control ultimately derives from
>   MarshalByRefObject that it can
>   successfully be remoted; this is not
>   true. Certain interfaces on a control
>   can be remoted across domains, but the
>   control’s API itself does not support
>   remoting. When you see exceptions
>   stating that the object cannot be
>   remoted because it isn’t serializable,
>   what you’re seeing is that someone has
>   tried to cast the remote proxy to
>   Control.

Comment: Note - I am not using a control in a separate AppDomain space.  I am using Assembly.LoadFile() which loads assemblies into the current (and only) AppDomain space.

Comment: Please edit your question to make this crystal clear.  It is called the "primary appdomain".  You also need to clarify what "host" then means.

Comment: I modified the question.  I assumed Assembly.LoadFile() was enough to explain that everything is using a single, primary AppDomain.